# Unable to install subversion

Tags: apt, svn

I am trying to install subversion on my system, but am receiving an error:

```
Package 'subversion' has no installation candidate.
```

What should I do from here? Want to install the whole subversion. The  ubuntu I am using its version is 2004.4.2.0

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're running (1) whether it's *just* the `subversion` client that you would like to install, or a complete subversion installation. With this, it *might* be feasible to offer a solution ‍

Comment: what is in file `/etc/issue.net`?